# Write File in Java Android, Read the File with Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I'm trying to write a json file using android like this:

```
String jsonString = broadcastDataArray.toString();
Writer output = null;

File fileAnnouncement = new File("announcement.json");
try  {
    output = new  BufferedWriter(new  FileWriter(fileAnnouncement));
    output.write(jsonString);
        output.close();
    } catch  (IOException e) {
    // TODO  Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and now i'm trying to load/read the file using phonegap. Using this method shown [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json), i am able to read a file that was included in my application source. But i want to read some file that was generated by the android code.

Is there anyway to do this? Is there any specific directory where the file could be accessed from Java android and Phonegap/Sencha ?

Any kind of help or pointer is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in following way.

Write this function in your Android activity to write data in text file.

```
public void WriteDataToFile(String sFileName, String sBody){
        try
        {
            FileWriter f = new FileWriter("/sdcard/data.txt");
            f.append(sBody);
            f.flush();
            f.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And, now you can read that file from your Sencha/Phonegap app by calling this function.

```
var user_data = function(){
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            request.open("GET", "/sdcard/data.txt");
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                    // alert("*" + request.responseText + "*");
                    data = request.responseText;                            
                }
            }
            request.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm able to verify that my file is written on this address: /sdcard/data.json

Comment: Also I found that i could use the raw address on sencha url like '/sdcard/data.json'. Thanks Pratik

Comment: Yes that is also possible from sencha too. Thanks.